# Refused to load the script. It violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: javascript

Refused to load the script 'https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: That is indeed an error message. It is rather self explanatory, once you do a very small amount of research on CSP. `script-src 'self'` limits the `src` of `script` elements to the origin of the document, so unless you're writing code for unpkg.com, it is unlikely the CSP will allow third-party scripts.